# Day/Night Mode Not Working On Initial Startup

Tags: java, android, android-night-mode

Very strange problem here. I'm going around in circles with it!

Day/Night mode seems to be working fine throughout my app...but for `INVISIBLE` drawables only, it is **not working on initial load.**

I have 2 xml drawable folders:
`drawable` and `drawable-night` with matching .png filenames

I have two values folders:
`values` with `colors.xml`, `styles.xml`, `ic_launcher_background.xml` and `strings.xml` - and also -
`values-night` with `colors.xml` and `styles.xml`

In the app I set the Mode using a toggle switch for Day/Night mode as per below. This seems to work fine.

```
dayNightMode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            System.out.println("Not Checked");
            InitApplication.getInstance().setIsNightModeEnabled(true, context);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            dayNightMode.setText("Night Mode");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Checked");
            InitApplication.getInstance().setIsNightModeEnabled(false, context);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            dayNightMode.setText("Day Mode");
        }
    }
});
```

The `InitApplication` class being called by the above code is:

```
package com.dmurphy.remotescrumpoker;

    import android.app.Application;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class InitApplication extends Application {
        public static final String NIGHT_MODE = "NIGHT_MODE";
        private boolean isNightModeEnabled = false;

        private static InitApplication singleton = null;

        public static InitApplication getInstance() {

            if(singleton == null)
            {
                singleton = new InitApplication();
            }
            return singleton;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            singleton = this;
            Context appContext = this.getApplicationContext();

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = appContext.getSharedPreferences("com.dmurphy.remotescrumpoker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            isNightModeEnabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(NIGHT_MODE, true);
            Log.i("onCreate1_", String.valueOf(isNightModeEnabled));
        }

        public boolean isNightModeEnabled(Context context) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("com.dmurphy.remotescrumpoker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            isNightModeEnabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(NIGHT_MODE, true);
            Log.i("onCreate11_", String.valueOf(isNightModeEnabled));
            return isNightModeEnabled;
        }

        public void setIsNightModeEnabled(boolean isNightModeEnabled, Context context) {
            this.isNightModeEnabled = isNightModeEnabled;
            Log.i("onCreate111_", String.valueOf(isNightModeEnabled));

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("com.dmurphy.remotescrumpoker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(NIGHT_MODE, isNightModeEnabled).apply();
            Log.i("onCreate1111_", String.valueOf(isNightModeEnabled));
        }
    }
```

I also have an `Activity_Poker` activity. Everything works fine, if I change the switch the app changes.

I also have a startup activity `Activity_Splash` and in the `onCreate` I check the mode:

```
if (InitApplication.getInstance().isNightModeEnabled(context)) {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate1_" + "Mode Night Yes");
} else {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate1_" + "Mode Night No");
}
setContentView(R.layout.activity__splash);
```

The startup works fine. When I close the app and restart, the background color etc. is correct for both Modes. I have 3 drawables `VISIBLE` on the activity at all times. These also change fine between the two alternative modes.

However, I have 9 drawables which are INVISIBLE by default. These become **VISIBLE** onCreate, but they **are always showing DAY_MODE on every load.**

**NOTE:** The drawables are **not in the wrong folders**. The correct colors are in the correct folders. The color of the 9 .png files which are not working, matches the 3 `VISIBLE` drawables which work fine. Just the default `INVISIBLE` ones are not populating from the `drawables-night` folder `onCreate`.

If I restart the Activity using the inApp user menu, the activity is recreated correctly with the `NIGHT_MODE` or `DAY_MODE` drawables as applicable. **But the NIGHT_MODE drawables (Fors ones which are INVISIBLE by default) are never used on startup.**

**EXPECTED OUTCOME:** On Startup, ImageView's which are INVISIBLE are changed to VISIBLE and populated with `drawables` for `DAY_MODE` or`drawables-night` for `NIGHT_MODE`.

**ACTUAL OUTCOME:** On Startup, ImageView's which are INVISIBLE are changed to VISIBLE and populated with `drawables` for `DAY_MODE` or`drawables` for `NIGHT_MODE`.

**Activity_Poker.java**

```
public class Activity_Poker extends AppCompatActivity {

[snip]
        Activity passedActivity = Activity_Poker.this;
[snip]
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_poker);
            drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    [snip]
            final String methodName = "onCreate";
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            String userId = mAuth.getUid();
    [snip]
            //Setup the UI for the selected game type
            int cardType = sharedPreferences.getInt("cardType", 0);
            Log.i(TAG, "Selected SharedPref Record: " + cardType);
            callSetupUI.setupLocalActive(passedActivity, cardType);
    [snip]
}
```

**NOTE:** `cardType` above shows correctly == 5 from the Logcat.

**SetupUI.java**

```
    public void setupLocalActive(Activity passedActivity, int cardType) {

        ImageView card4 = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard4);
        ImageView card4img = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard4img);
        ImageView card5 = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard5);
        ImageView card5img = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard5img);
        ImageView card6 = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard6);
        ImageView card6img = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard6img);
        ImageView card7 = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard7);
        ImageView card7img = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard7img);
        ImageView card8 = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard8);
        ImageView card8img = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard8img);
        ImageView card9 = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard9);
        ImageView card9img = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard9img);
        ImageView card11 = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard11);
        ImageView card11img = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.pokerCard11img);

        TextView card4TextView = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewPokerCard4);
        TextView card5TextView = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewPokerCard5);
        TextView card6TextView = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewPokerCard6);
        TextView card7TextView = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewPokerCard7);
        TextView card8TextView = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewPokerCard8);
        TextView card9TextView = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewPokerCard9);
        TextView card10TextView = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewPokerCard10);
        TextView card11TextView = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewPokerCard11);
        TextView card12TextView = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewPokerCard12);
        TextView card13TextView = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewPokerCard13);
        TextView card14TextView = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewPokerCard14);
        TextView card15TextView = passedActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewPokerCard15);

        Log.i(TAG, "Selected SharedPref Record UI CardType into Switch: " + cardType);

        switch (cardType){
            case 1:
[snip]
            case 2:
[snip]
            case 3:
[snip]
            case 4:
[snip]
            case 5:
                Log.i(TAG, "Selected SharedPref Record Setting UI: " + cardType);
                card10.setVisibility(card10.INVISIBLE);
                card12.setVisibility(card12.INVISIBLE);
                card13.setVisibility(card13.INVISIBLE);
                card14.setVisibility(card14.INVISIBLE);
                card15.setVisibility(card15.INVISIBLE);
                card4TextView.setVisibility(card4TextView.INVISIBLE);
                card5TextView.setVisibility(card5TextView.INVISIBLE);
                card6TextView.setVisibility(card6TextView.INVISIBLE);
                card7TextView.setVisibility(card7TextView.INVISIBLE);
                card8TextView.setVisibility(card8TextView.INVISIBLE);
                card9TextView.setVisibility(card9TextView.INVISIBLE);
                card10TextView.setVisibility(card10TextView.INVISIBLE);
                card11TextView.setVisibility(card10TextView.INVISIBLE);
                card12TextView.setVisibility(card12TextView.INVISIBLE);
                card13TextView.setVisibility(card13TextView.INVISIBLE);
                card14TextView.setVisibility(card14TextView.INVISIBLE);
                card15TextView.setVisibility(card15TextView.INVISIBLE);

                card4img.setImageResource(R.drawable.chihuahua);
                card5img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dachshund);
                card6img.setImageResource(R.drawable.beagle);
                card7img.setImageResource(R.drawable.spaniel);
                card8img.setImageResource(R.drawable.boxer);
                card9img.setImageResource(R.drawable.shepard);
                card11img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dane);

                card4img.setVisibility(card4img.VISIBLE);
                card5img.setVisibility(card5img.VISIBLE);
                card6img.setVisibility(card6img.VISIBLE);
                card7img.setVisibility(card7img.VISIBLE);
                card8img.setVisibility(card8img.VISIBLE);
                card9img.setVisibility(card9img.VISIBLE);
                card11img.setVisibility(card11img.VISIBLE);

                break;

            default:
[snip]
                break;
        }

    }
```

**activity_poker.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="260dp">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp">

[snip]
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pokerCard5"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="104dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:contentDescription="@string/localCardSelectcontent"
            android:onClick="card8clicked"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pokerCard6"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pokerCard4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pokerCard2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pokerCard5img"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/localCardSelectcontent"
            android:onClick="localcard5clicked"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pokerCard5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pokerCard5"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dachshund" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPokerCard5"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="104dp"
            android:onClick="localcard5clicked"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="44sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pokerCard5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pokerCard5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pokerCard4"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="104dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:contentDescription="@string/localCardSelectcontent"
            android:onClick="card5clicked"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pokerCard5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pokerCard5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pokerCard4img"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/localCardSelectcontent"
            android:onClick="localcard4clicked"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pokerCard4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pokerCard4"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/chihuahua" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPokerCard4"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="104dp"
            android:onClick="localcard4clicked"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="44sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pokerCard4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pokerCard4" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:onClick="onSwitchChange"
    app:headerLayout= "@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@xml/drawer_view" >

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the correct solution, but I implemented a workaround.

In `Activity_Splash` I added a bool to indicate that its the initial startup.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Activity_Splash.this.getSharedPreferences("com.dmurphy.remotescrumpoker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("initialStartup", true).apply();
```

In Activity_Poker I retrieved the bool and if NIGHT_MODE is enabled and 'initialStartup' is true, I restart the Activity_Poker to reset the UI.

```
boolean initialStartup = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("initialStartup", false);
if (InitApplication.getInstance().isNightModeEnabled(context) && initialStartup) {

    callUserMenu.menuAction(TAG, methodName, context, 5, passedActivity); //This triggers my Intent to restart the activity
    sharedPreferences.edit().remove("initialStartup").apply();
}
```

Still have no idea whats actually causing this.